# iOS photo editor's "marker" markup tool is translucent…is opaque possible?

Tags: ios, photos.app, markup

The "marker" markup tool in iOS 11 photo editor is translucent. Is it possible to make it opaque?

Comment: The highlighter is translucent, would you be open to using the pen tool? It is opaque but one would have to change the color and perhaps use more strokes for coverage.

Comment: I'm choosing the pen with the widest chisel, to minimize strokes, with the color of black.

Comment: So, to be sure, you wish for an opaque chiseled style pen like the highlighter has, correct?

Comment: When I choose wide chisel, black color, I expect not a highlighter.

Comment: Depending on the iOS device, pressing harder with the PEN tool, not the HIGHLIGHTER (which looks like a “marker” will make a heavier stroke and is opaque.  I know of no way to change the stroke opacity of the highlighter tool.  I’m hesitant to put this as answer.

Comment: My screen is not pressure-sensitive (iPhone SE).

Comment: There only 2 pen options... a pen and an highlighter.

Comment: Again, the color is black—not a highlighter.

Comment: I realize that, and I wish I could help you.  (Smile). But even though you can change the color of the Highlighter tool to black, it is still a highlighter, not a chiseled marker.  (Resulting in translucent black color). That’s (unfortunately) how Apple designed it.  As a suggestion, you may want to edit your question perhaps including an image with an example.  There may be other editing apps or tools that could be suggested here in potential answers.